# Fixed four degree reducible polynomial

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I find the largest possible number of distinct integer values $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n\}$, such that for a fixed reducible degree four polynomial with integer coefficients, $|f(x_i)|$ is prime for all $i$?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the polynomial is reducible, then it can be written as P(x) = Q(x)R(x) and |P(x)| can be prime only if |Q(x)| or |R(x)| is 1. This relates to the zeros of Q(x)±1 and R(x)±1, and so an upper bound is 8.

Edit: It looks like the bound can be attained: $n^4-2n^3-9n^2+10n+5$ is prime (in absolute value) for -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: $2x^2-1$ is $1$ in absolute value at $-1,0,1$ and prime at $2,3,4$, so $|(2x^2-1)(2(3-x)^2-1)|$ is prime at 6 different integer values of $x$. I don't see how 8 can be attained (but I could be missing something).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I didn't know either, but looking into it I found that it is! I edited in an example.